# SQL Query to retrieve the list of Running / Enable Jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 100's of jobs running in my agent. Some of the jobs are running / ENABLED.

some jobs are not running / ENABLED. Some jobs are NOT ENABLED.

Below query helps me to fetch all enable / not enable job list.

```
      SELECT
     job.job_id,
     notify_level_email,
     name,
     enabled,
     description
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

I need a query to find only running / enable jobs. I couldnt find that query.
I forgot to tell. This is on SQL 2000. We don't have   msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity

Comment: Add a where clause `where enabled = 1`

Answer (score 1):

To find all the jobs enabled use the following:

```
SELECT
     job_id,
     notify_level_email,
     name,
     enabled,
     description
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
where enabled = 1
```

To find all the jobs running and enabled use the following:

```
SELECT   j.job_id,
         j.notify_level_email,
         j.name,
         j.enabled,
         j.description,
         ja.start_execution_date
FROM       msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity  ja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs         j  ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE ja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
  AND ja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

Comment: i forgot tell ..this is on Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)  . We don't have   msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity